# IIS 7 Site & application relationship

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm trying to configure an ASP.NET MVc application to work under IIS.
I've created IIS Site called SyncControlPanel which has a binding set to mydomain.com.

This IIS site has one application inside : SynchronizationService. Now when I want to access my application I need to type: http://mydomain.com/SynchronizationService.

What I want to do is to be able to access my application simply by typing http://mydomain.com
What am I supposed to do with this? Is there a way to set an application to be the sites default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the default folder at the root of the site to point to your application's file system folder.
2. Ensure the root folder uses the correct app pool.

And that should be it (the root of a web site is always an application—the default application normal and virtual directories that are not themselves applications will be part of).